# Twitter Kafka Connect Source to Avro Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I have been coding a custom kafka connector that read from the twitter api and write in a kafka topic, I have been trying to use avro coding to write those message and i found that it was very difficult. The technologies used were confluent docker kafka images 3.1.2 and kafka client 0.10.1.0. For generating the avro object I used the maven plugin avro-maven-plugin, that generates the object with the schema correctly. But, I have found that, for creating the source record, I have to replicate the same schema in java code creating a custom "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema" and then, inform a org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct object with all the information. As a value converter class, I use the AvroConverter, and reviewing the code, the only form to send a custom object, is sending it as Struct object, it the, create the avro format and use it for encoding the object. I don't understand why it can not digest my custom class created by the avro maven plugin to serialize the object. I dont now if this is the correct form to create a connector with avro serializer.

Could I get some feedbacks about this solution?
Thanks to everyone.
Xoan.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement it yourself? There are at least 2 implementations of it, for example: https://github.com/Eneco/kafka-connect-twitter

Comment: Yes I  know, I just wanted to implement a connector that write into a topic with avro serializer, so I could learn how to do it and which are the best practices, I found very difficult do it and I don't know if there is an easier way than  coding a Struct and Schema for the avro coding.